# How to make a component render conditionally depending on drop down choices on button click. (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm trying to use element variables found in the React documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. I'm not sure why it is not rendering the component I have stored in the Output variable.

Submit:

```
    import './Submit.css'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Output from '../Output/Output'

function Submit(props) {
    let output;

    const process = () => {
        console.log(output)
        if(props.src === "x" && props.tgt === "y") { 
            output = <Output src={props.src} tgt={props.tgt}/>
            }
        }

    return (
    <>
    <button 
    disabled={props.src === "Source Chain" || props.tgt === "Target Chain"}
    onClick={() => process()} className="submit">Submit
    </button>
    {output}
    </>
    );

};



export default Submit;
```

Output component:

```
    import './Output.css'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Output (props) {
    return (
       <div className="content">;
           <a className="contenttitle">{props.src} to {props.tgt}</a>
           <h3 className="contentboxtitle"></h3>
           <div className ="liquidassets"> </div>
           <h3 className="contentboxtitle"></h3>
           <div className ="liquidassets"> </div>
       </div>
    )
}





export default Output;
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `{someBooleanExp ? output: someOtherElement}` if the boolean evaluates to true it'll show the output' otherwise the other element. you can put there just null

Comment: Please try replacing `let output;` with `const [someFlag, setSomeFlag] = useState(false);`. Then, change `{output}` to `{someFlag && <Output src={props.src} tgt={props.tgt}/>}`. Finally, the `process` method should be changed to something like: `const process = () => setSomeFlag((props.src === "x" && props.tgt === "y"));`

Answer (score 0):

Use a state to control the button and use that state to render or not render your output component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function SystemsButtonGroup() {
  const [showOutput, setShowOutput] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowOutput(!showOutput)} className="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
      {showOutput && <div>Replace this with your output component</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```